# cURL PHP works on one server but doesn't on another

Tags: php, curl

Hi I know the question is very general, but what are the possibilities why there is an issue (blocked  cURL on the server or whatever). 
So the problem is I make the cURL request to another domain in PHP (code below)

```html
$url = 'https://www.example.com/get_products.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result= curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

And on the website at hosting provider A it works great, but on the hosting provider B it doesn't work. Can't access to provider B website right now so can't debug it using **curl_errno** etc. So what are the possibilities it doesnt't work there.

Comment: Well, if you have no possibility to debug any problem, there is not much to help. One simple recommendation could be to stop using cURL directly and use some library like Guzzle which will help you handle exceptions

Comment: Curl may not be installed on server B system? PHP Curl extension may also not be installed?
Your question is broad, you should add some errors / debug informations.

Answer (score 3):

In sometime servers also don't support the CURL so may be that issue happen.

Please check your hosting provider or ask for kind support.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases outgoing ports are blocked. So check your connection with telnet for example:

```
telnet www.example.com 443
```

If this is connecting then you know that the port is open otherwise you should call your provider and ask them to open the port.

The next thing is that sometimes the SSL-Verification isn't working well. So you can disable the CURL option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to disable it for temporary tests. Please don't use that in production because then your certificate isn't checked. But you can test if this is the problem.

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html

The last thing you could try is to use curl on the CLI and use the debug mode.

```
curl -v https://www.example.com/get_products.php
```

With verbose you get a lot of information.